# Propellerheads Reason question: banking clips? how?

Tags: reason, how-to

Fresh Reason newb here, looking for a functionality that seems obvious, but I can't figure out how to do it.

As I create clips on the Sequencer, whether it be a drum pattern in Korg or a melody in Europa, I find myself wanting to build a "folder" of different clips that I can store apart from the Sequencer, and drop in and out of the Sequencer as needed. I could label the clips "cool melody" or basic beat" or "crescendo moment", storing them somewhere apart from the Sequencer to bring a copy of them out as needed.

I mean, as I dork around, I'm coming up with some interesting grooves, beats, and melodies and I would like some place to save them for later use. How do I do that?

To be clear, I am not talking about saving songs, but the clips one creates on the Sequencer.

Comment: This sounds like a question far more relevant to Propellerheads' own support structure.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Reason does not have this capability. However, it has a different capability that adds a similar though very distinct functionality called "blocks" - worth checking out if you like me wanted a similar thing.